# Polymorphic relations between three models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I just can't figure out how to solve this problem:

I got different models like this:

- `Doctor`
- `Patient`
- `Insurance`

Now each of these Models should be linkable by a `Contract`.

So for example:

- The `Doctor` also has a `Contract` with the `Patient`.   (with some data like date-fields , ...).
- The `Patient` has a `Contract` with the `Doctor`  (with some data like date-fields , ...).
- The `Patient` has a `Contract` with the `Insurance` (with some data like date-fields , ...).

So I guess I'd create a relation like `morphMany` for all the models. The `Contract` `morphsTo` the `contractable`.

But I am not sure how to specify the "link" between the models. The `Contract`-table would need to save the `id` and the `type` of the morphed  model - but how would I store the "target" model?

Comment: Are you sure these contracts would be the same conceptually? It looks to me like it should be split up between Doctor-Patient Contract and Insurance Contract.

Comment: Alternatively since Patient is the common link, your morph pivot table should have the columns `patient_id` `contractable_id`, `contractable_type` (Doctor, Insurance).